# StackTrace - описание с примерами для новичка в Java

Tags: java, stacktrace

Пытаюсь постичь основы джавы, используя javarush, гугл, ютуб и прочие инструменты. Дошел до темы StackTrace и подзавис. Много вопросов вылезло:

1. С помощью StackTrace определяется порядок работы методов  и можно определить место  возникновения ошибки во время исполнения программы. Это основная его функция или есть еще? Какие?
2. StackTraceElement[] - где развернуто можно почитать про него и `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` (желательно объяснения "на пальцах")?

Comment: `Пытаюсь постичь основы джавы, используя javarush, гугл, ютуб и прочие инструменты` -- это плохая идея. Фундаментальные вещи нужно изучать по книгам. Шилдт, Эккель, Хорстманн.

Comment: Скажу вам то что никто не скажет. Хотите выучить Java проста прочитайте книгу head first Java.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 книга хорошая, но не стоит только ей ограничиваться

Comment: @MikhailVaysman конечно не стоит ограничиваться.Но это книга даст вам нужное знания так как никто  другой не сможет дать.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 уверенны, что она мне хоть что-то даст? :) например, знание по функциональным возможностям языка даст?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вам ничего так как вы уже профессионал.Это книга может научить новичку многим аспектам программирования.Книги Head First самые ценные книги по программирование каких я когда либо читал.Лучше их ничего не может помочь новичку выучить язык.А для профессионала можно выбрать что нибудь продвинутое.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 думаю курс теории в сочетании с пачкой задач на эту тему (а не примеров из книги) будет чуточку полезнее. Тем более, что в определенный момент в курсе ученику говорят о важности книг (с указанием книг). У каждого свое восприятие (визуальное, слуховое и прочее)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> С помощью StackTrace определяется порядок работы методов и можно определить место возникновения ошибки во время исполнения программы. Это основная его функция или есть еще? Какие?

Не "порядок", а стэк (типа "дерево" с одинарными ветвями) вызовов. Да, определять место возникн. ошибки - это основная функция. Но может применяться не только для ошибок, а еще и чтобы просто определить место выполнения - в логировании при реверс-инжиниринге и т.п.
Применяется даже в системах защиты от инъекций кода, который вызывает методы не от действий пользователя, а автоматически (типа бот) и по s.t. это выявляется.

> StackTraceElement[] - где развернуто можно почитать про него

В документации есть все. Что о нем читать? Попробуйте на практике и станет понятно.

> Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

Аналогично.

> буду рад каждому ответу!

Кнопка "За" слева, галочка под ней.